# Symfony hidrating limits the number of results of a left join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am executing a DQL query with Doctrine with a left join.

Entity Lead

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="presupuestos")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Buv\MarketplaceBundle\Repository\LeadRepository")
 */
class Lead {
  /**
   * @var integer $id
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @var LeadPayment $leadPayment
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="LeadPayment", mappedBy="lead")
   */
  private $leadPayment;

  ...
```

Entity LeadPayment

```
/**
 * Buv\MarketplaceBundle\Entity\LeadPayment
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="presupuestos_payment")
 */
class LeadPayment {

  /**
   * @var integer $id
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
  private $id;

  /**
   * @var integer $leadId
   * @ORM\Column(name="presupuesto_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   */
  private $leadId;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lead", inversedBy="leadPayment")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="presupuesto_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $lead;


  ...
```

*Actually there are more tables involved, but I detected that the problem is with LeadPayment, so I simplified the explanation not to put so much code here.*

So I do the following DQL:

```
SELECT l, lp
FROM BuvMarketplaceBundle:Lead l
LEFT JOIN l.leadPayment lp
```

There are results that are being skipped because of the relation with leadPayment. If I comment the LEFT JOIN then I get the correct results (but then need to lazy load all the records with leadPayment)

The strange thing is that in the SQL query executed that I see in the Symfony debug toolbar works great and the results are correct.
The problem seems to be in the hidrating process.

Comment: Why do you define `$leadId` ? That probably breaks the hydrating since it's redundant with `$lead` and the column has the same name.

Comment: @tchap I updated the phpdoc info because the table and field names are not the same (I ommited this in the original question 'cos I thought if wasn't important)

Comment: You still don't need the `$leadId` field ... your 'field not found' error comes from somewhere else. Clear the cache and create a new database to test your model but it should run fine

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to define the `$leadId` field manually, Doctrine takes care of that for you. You also don't need to `JoinColumn`, because you're just using the default values anyway. In other words, replace this code in your LeadPayment entity:

```
  /**
   * @var integer $leadId
   * @ORM\Column(name="lead_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   */
  private $leadId;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lead", inversedBy="leadPayment")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lead_id", referencedColumnName="id")
   */
  private $lead;
```

With just this:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lead", inversedBy="leadPayment")
   */
  private $lead;
```

Comment: Sorry, in the question I omited some info I thought it wasn't important, like that the table name is not the same. I edited with the info on tables and real field names.
By the way I tried to avoid defining the $leadId property and then I get a "field not found" error.

Comment: @Sergi Are you bound to those names because of a legacy database or something? It's usually best to avoid any custom naming and to follow convention wherever you can.

Comment: yes I need to mantain the BD names, and the classnames and properties too. The database is shared with another project and in this one there is a lot of code related to Lead entity.